# why isn't the proc loop through each element of the array(ruby)?

Tags: ruby

```
trio = Proc.new do |x|
  tf = true
  puts x
  if tf 
    puts "ai yo"
  end

end

trio.call([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

output:

> 1 2 3 4 5 ai yo #its only doing the ai yo part only once when I believe it
>   should do it after every number

but What I am expecting of output is:

> 1 ai yo 2 ai yo 3 ai yo 4 ai yo 5 ai yo

I still cant wrap my head around why this is happening.

Im trying to get this program to work that i thought would be a cool way to use procs although in this specific problem i dont need to basically:

```
#The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
#What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

number = 13195

def factorsAndOptions(num, proc = Proc.new {|x|return x})
  factorsArray = []
  for i in 1..num
    factorsArray.push(i) if num % i == 0
  end
  proc.call(factorsArray)
end

largestPrime = Proc.new do |x|
  prime = true
  for j in 2...x
    if (x % x == 0)
      prime = false
   end
  end
  larger = x if prime && larger > x
  puts larger
  larger
end

factorsAndOptions(number, largestPrime)
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: there is no loop in your code. Why would you expect it to loop?

Comment: Apologies, I thought that when an array is used in a proc then | x | would act the same as | x | would when using .each on an array.

Answer (score 6):

`call` won't iterate over arguments. What you've written is, effectively:

```
puts [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
puts "ai yo"
```

If you want to iterate, use `each`:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].each(&trio)
```

Or:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].each { |i| trio.call(i) }
```

Comment: the reason I want to do this is because I have a program that im trying to solve, i've came up with an idea to use different procs in a function that will make the method do slightly different things:

Comment: I added the code that I'm trying to get to work in the way i want into my question

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned, you do not have any looping block. Your proc - `trio` is acting on the whole array as one single element.

In your example: `x` becomes `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and not individual elements of the array as you are expecting.

---

To circumvent this you can either loop inside your Proc or create a separate Proc that will loop over the elements of the array and call the first Proc.

**Example 1**

```
trio = Proc.new do |arr|
  arr.each do |elem|
    puts elem
    if tf
      puts "ai yo"
    end
  end
end
```

This assumes that `arr` is an array

**Example 2**

```
trio = Proc.new do |x|
  tf = true
  puts x
  if tf
    puts "ai yo"
  end

end


trio_helper = Proc.new do |x| 
 arr = x.to_a
 arr.each do |elem|
   trio.call(elem)
 end
end

trio_helper.call([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

This utilizes the original Proc you have written and uses another Proc to iterate over the array and call the first one on each element.